# What is the part of speech of a word that refers to the word itself

Tags: parts-of-speech

If I say:

> Some words that I like are: "desk", "lovely", and "enticingly".

What parts of speech are the quoted words?

Used in a typical sentence they'd be: noun, adjective, and adverb respectively. But it doesn't seem right that this distinction should also be made in the sentence above.

(This wikipedia page is as far as I got in my research: [Use–mention distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_as_words)

Comment: They are nouns.

Comment: I suppose they're the names of entities, which indicates the noun class.

Comment: There's a difference between "lovely" and ""lovely"": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all nouns. Regardless of the part of speech of the word being referred to, it is a word, and a word is a thing.